# C++ pthread hand over object to thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

I think with my code, I hand over the address of the object to the thread.
However I cannot access the object directly (args.getTerminationStatus).

Unfortunately I only make a copy of that passed object and therefore changes of attributes take no effect (the while loop ist running forever, even thought the attribute behind getTerminationStatus() has changed outside). Would be nice if you have some ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
int main(){

    Sensors barometer(1, "Barometer", 0); //ID, Description, Value

    pthread_t t1;
    int ret1;
    ret1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &barometerThread, &barometer); //Hand over object to thread
    if(ret1 != 0){
        cout << "Error: Thread 1 (Luftdruckmesser) konnte nicht erstellt werden." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sleep(10);
    barometer.finish(); // Sets TerminationStatus to true
```

```
void *barometerThread(void *args){

    Sensors dev = *(Sensors *) (args); // I think this is just a copy of that passed object

    cout << "Luftdruck-Thread gestartet. Device-ID: " << dev.getID() << " Descr.: " << dev.getDescription() << " Value: " << dev.getValue() << endl;

    while (!dev.getTerminationStatus()){
        cout << "Still in loop: " << dev.getTerminationStatus() << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Comment: is there a reason you are not using `std::thread`?

Comment: ot: your `barometerThread` is missing the `return`, this is undefined behavior

Comment: the error seems to be from different code. The error message complains about `args.getID()` but in your code you have the correct `dev.getID()`

Comment: ooooh. I get it. Please post the code code that actually has the error your question is about. Code in comments is easily overlooked and does not produce compiler errors

Comment: ? your edit made it worse. Now it is more difficult to understand the quesiton. Why do you not show the broken code together with the resulting error message?

Comment: @user2864740 OP is talking of the copy they are making in the body

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. Nice hint with std::thread. Maybe someone has an idea with my problem. If not, I switch so std::thread and hopefully I have no trouble with passing objects there

Comment: you should switch to `std::thread` anyhow. Your current issue is just one of the difficulties with bare pthreads

Comment: @user2864740 `Sensors dev = *(Sensors *) (args);` first line in `barometerThread`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Uhg. So [the copy] having nothing to do with threads at all.

Comment: Ever since C++11 which is now ten years old, there has been no reason to use pthreads directly in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the copy by changing the conversion line to:

```
Sensors& dev = *(Sensors *) (args);
```

so that now it will be a reference to a `Sensors` object rather than a copy.

Assuming `getID()` is a `Sensors` class method you can then do:

```
cout << dev.getID();
```

after you've converted it.

If you haven't considered it yet, using `std::thread` would make life a bit easier here (since it accepts `std::function`s which you can bind arbitrary typed data to). Another thing to keep in mind is that the `Sensors` class instance will be accessed from two threads, so make sure `barometer.finish()` and `dev.getTerminationStatus()` are both thread safe!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make a copy. As you are absolutely certain that the `void*` you pass to the function is pointing to a `Sensor` you can cast the pointer:

```
void *barometerThread(void *args){
    Sensor* dev_ptr = (Sensor*)args;
  
    // ....
```

Usually a proper C++ cast (`static_cast`/`dynamic_cast`) should be prefered, though as we are dealing with a `void*` and anyhow it is all up to you to make sure that the cast is correct, a c-style cast is "ok".

Note that you are missing the `return` in the function but it must return a `void*`. If it does not you invoke undefined behavior. Also there is `std::thread` which keeps you away from such `void*` anachronisms.

Comment: Your answer is also correct and works. Unfortunately I cannot mark two answers as "solved", The only difference is, that I have to use "->" operator to access the attributes/methods instead of the "." dot.